# Clojure: Why surrounding an expression with extra parenthesis gives NullPointerException

Tags: clojure

I created two functions in clojure

```
(defn incc [n] ((Thread/sleep 1000) (+ n 1)))
```

and

```
(defn incc [n] (Thread/sleep 1000) (+ n 1))
```

The first one threw a Null pointer Exception while the other worked like the built in `inc` function. Any clue why ?

Note: I'm testing lazy seq, hence the `Thread/sleep`

Comment: In your first example (Thread/sleep 1000) returns nil so you end up calling -> (nil ....) which throws a NP

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, I think: the question itself and half the answer are different. If this question had been asked first, the other could be marked duplicate, as this question text precisely describes the fault. The opposite is not the case. In fact, why don't we mark [the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40229259/wrong-number-of-args-0-passed-to-persistentvector-on-loop-recur-function) as a duplicate of this.

Comment: I'll throw down a comment-answer just in case the dupe doesn't answer your question. Remember that the first symbol that appears in a form is what is being called. When you write `((println "text"))`, first the `println` form is evaluated, and returns `nil`. Then you're left with `(nil)`. Since you have a form again, it will try to call the first symbol in the form: `nil`. Of course that doesn't make sense though, since `nil` isn't callable, so you get a NPE. Think of it this way, in a language like Python or Java, what would you expect `None()` to do? Or `null()`?